# WCF Data Service and how i can use store procedure to gridview?

Tags: wcf, stored-procedures, execute

I am using WCF Data Service. I want use stored procedure so that its results were in the GridView. I found examples using the Execute method, such as

http://www.codegain.com/articles/wcf/miscellaneous/how-to-use-stored-procedure-in-wcf-data-service.aspx

But the compiler does not recognize the execute method in my case, not at all in Intelisens. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have imported the required namespaces? I just checked, and the following code compiles just fine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
//DataServiceContext
using System.Data.Services;
using System.Data.Services.Client;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public class StudentGrade
        {
            //ClassDefinition
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataServiceContext context = new DataServiceContext(new Uri("http://URI"));

            List<StudentGrade> lstStudentsGrade = context.Execute<StudentGrade>
                   (new Uri("http://URI")).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Ensure you have imported `System.Data.Services` and `System.Data.Services.Client` before you try to use the DataServiceContext class and the .Execute<>() method.